# Standard Input for C program using Unix Command Line

Tags: c, unix, stdin

I have the following section of code in C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *input;
    int lines;
    int p;


    input = (char*)malloc(10);
    input = argv[0];
    for(p=0;p<10;p++)
    {
        printf("%c",input[p]);
    }
```

On my Unix system I make the following call:

```
./program_name.exe < inputfile
```

where `inputfile` is a file that contains the following: `000000010Z`

The output I receive to the previous commands is:

```
./program_
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If the goal is to read stdin, you may want to read about getc(), fgets() or scanf().

Comment: the malloc is useless, you aren't using that allocated buffer, the < inputfile isn't a parameter to your program, its redirecting the stdin into your program

Comment: argv[0] is the program name.  argv[1] is the first command line parameter.  If you redirect a file into stdin you either need to open stdin as a file inside your program and read from it (fopen, fgets, fclose) or read ketstrokes (getchar, gets) which will return the same thing.

Comment: It looks like you're missing "name.exe".  Try looping to 18 instead of 10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[0]`  holds name of program being executed. And that's the only thing you print.

What you're trying to do is to read from your file as it was stdin. But you still have to read it. Use getchar(), or any other function that reads input.

Comment: Yep, thats it.  Thank you for the help!